# Add count value to a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a forum page using MySQL as database, but I'm coming from MongoDB and am a bit confused. When I fetch all posts for a specific category it looks something like this

```
SELECT p.id, p.posted_at, p.title, p.content, c.name AS category_name, u.name 
AS author_name
FROM posts AS p
INNER JOIN users AS u ON p.author = u.id
INNER JOIN categories AS c ON p.category = c.id
WHERE p.category = 3 <-- Category ID
```

People can follow posts so I have a table called user_post_relations which contains two columns; user_id and post_id. 
My goal is to add a follower count per post to the query that's getting all the posts per category. How can this be achieved with only one query?

Comment: Using COUNT() and a GROUP BY expression.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks for your answer! If it's not too much to ask for, can you please give me an example?
Cheers!

Comment: @KenWhite Instead of being rude you don't have to answer... If you don't like my answer then just let it be. I asked for an example, not the solution. 
Thank you.

Comment: Not being rude. Trying to teach you to fish rather than ask for a meal. Better protection against starvation if you learn how to feed yourself. When I ask a question and someone says *You could do it using this thing*, my reaction is not *Please show me how*. Instead, I start searching with Google using that information and see if I can figure it out. I learn a lot more a lot faster, and I spend more time getting things done than I do waiting for others to do it for me. But OK, an example: `SELECT ID, COUNT(*) FROM Test GROUP BY ID`. Much better ones in the link I gave you, though.

Comment: @KenWhite Of course I research on my own. This is my second question here. I still don't get how I can use the GROUP BY and COUNT when I have to do the counting in another table. I have researched combining queries and using union but it has not helped me so far, therefor I asked this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following JOIN with sub-query to your query

```
JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) follower_count
      FROM user_post_relations
      GROUP BY post_id) AS upr ON upr.post_id = p.id
```

And then add `upr.follower_count` to your SELECT list

Comment: Tack så mycket! It works! So the idea here is to group all the post_ids in the relation table and then count them, have I understood you correctly then? :)